# SonarQube MSBuild runner fails on deactivated rule

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube5.1.2, sonarqube-msbuild-runner

SonarQube MSBuild runner fails if I deactivate FxCop rule in quality profile:

*Unable to find the rule key corresponding to the rule config key 'CA1305' in in repository "fxcop".*

I've bulk-added all the fxcop rules. Added a project. Then then deactivated some rules in quality profile and tried to analyze *new* project.
Even there was NOT any violations of this rule in code - runner still fails with this weird error.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that you are somehow importing an FxCop report that contains `CA1305` issues after you disabled the rule in your repository.

The error message you see is being generated here, and this method is only called during the parsing of the FxCop report: https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-fxcop-library/blob/1.3/src/main/java/org/sonar/plugins/fxcop/FxCopSensor.java#L179

Could you try:

1. Disable the `CA1305` rule in your quality profile
2. Run: `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner begin /k:... /n:... /v:...`
3. `msbuild /t:rebuild`
4. `MSBuild.SonarQube.Runner end`

Then, could you verify that:

5. In the generated file `.sonarqube\conf\SonarQubeFxCop-cs.ruleset`, you don't see an entry for `CA1305`
6. You can find the location to the FxCop report in `.sonarqube\out\*\ProjectInfo.xml` - look for the `<AnalysisResult Id="FxCop" Location="..."`
7. Within that report, there is no occurence of `CA1305`