# Sonarqube 5.2 with custom fxcop rules is not working

Tags: sonarqube, fxcop, sonarqube5.2

I upgraded sonarqube to 5.2.  I replaced the old instance with a new instance, so the old configuration was deleted and replaced.

I have several custom fxcop rules. 
[image]

When running the analysis, I am getting the following error.
ERROR: Error during Sonar runner execution
ERROR: Unable to execute Sonar
ERROR: Caused by: Unable to find the rule key corresponding to the rule config key "HSI1009" in repository "fxcop".

This is caused by empty entries in the sonar created file fxcop-sonarqube.ruleset file.[image]

Does anyone know if this is a bug or some error on my end?  I did not have these sorts of issues before the 5.2 upgrade, but unable to go back due to reliance on some plugins using 5.2.

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33128920/sonarqube-msbuild-runner-fails-on-deactivated-rule) help ?

Comment: @n_stan - That is exactly my issue, but I am unable to fix.

Answer (score 1):

I was only able to fix this by downgrading back to SonarQube 5.1.2.  Even though I am using the same C# plugin (5.0) and the same runner version (2.5), upgrading to SonarQube 5.2 and up broke custom fxcop rules.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has been fixed with the SonarQube Scanner for MSBuild v1.0.2+ : https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARMSBRU-151
Also be sure to run the SQ Scanner for MSBuild in a .NET 4.5.2 context.

Comment: Cannot use the new msbuild runner.  I am using the older runner because I want to commit each VS project (about 800+) into its own sonarqb project.  We have a pretty large monolithic source code.  Anyway to fix this for the older runner?